# Инфоблоки Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток.

Недавно начал изучать Laravel, до этого был небольшой опыт с битрикс.
Вопрос, если ли какая-то библиотека или встроенный функционал по созданию инфоблоков в laravel?

Технически это три таблицы SQl:

1. главная таблица с общими полями (может включать n-сущностей)
2. таблица свойств сущностей
3. таблица значений

В моем представлении, есть какая-то базовая модель которая дружит с таблицами, можно от нее наследоваться и плодить сущности не трогая БД

Comment: Технически Вы описываете EAV-модель базы данных. Что конкретно Вы хотите получить?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, Владимир, спасибо! Я не знал про эту модель из-за чего гуглил на китайском. Нашел пару библиотек, буду читать доки по ним. Еще раз большое СПАСИБО!)